# jquery selectors -- finding a child of the root node

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

It seems that this should be simple, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to construct a selector that will return only elements that are a direct child of a root node.

If, for example, I have a reference to a div (myDiv), and I want to select only images that are direct children of that div, the following doesn't work:

```
jQuery("div > img", myDiv);
```

The "div" in the selector doesn't seem to match the root of the context, only descendants, and without a selector that will give me the root, I can't use ">". Any other ideas on how to select a direct child of a context root?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't repeat the div tag:

```
jQuery("> img",myDiv);
```

Comment: cool. thought I tried that, but guess I didn't. Seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

if mydiv is a reference to a jQuery object

```
mydiv.children("img")
```

else

```
$(mydiv).children("img")
jQuery(mydiv).children("img")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only direct descendents, you want [children](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children#expr).

```
jQuery(myDiv).children('img')
```

or, if it's a jquery object...

```
myDiv.children('img')
```

or, if not, you can also do...

```
jQuery('>img', myDiv)
```